# WPF Storyboard Event Binding

Tags: wpf, xaml

I am new to using WPF Storyboards, here is my code:

```
   <StackPanel>

    <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="Black" Height="40" Name="Border1"></Border>

    <Grid Height="0" Name="MyGrid" Background="Green">
        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UserControl.Loaded">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyGrid" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="0" To="40" 
                    Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>
    </Grid>

</StackPanel>
```

I would like to change the event that triggers the storyboard to start to Border1.MouseEnter.

Is this possible?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case, you should move the triggers to the Border control:

```
<StackPanel>

<Border Grid.Row="0" Background="Black" Height="40" Name="Border1">
   <Border.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Border.MouseEnter">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyGrid" 
                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="0" To="40" 
                       Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Border.Triggers>
</Border>

<Grid Height="0" Name="MyGrid" Background="Green">

</Grid>
```

Comment: Wow, can't believe I did not think of that! But like I said it is my first attempt. Thanx!

Answer (score 0):

I really didn't try it, but this should work:

```
<StackPanel>
<StackPanel.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter" SourceName="Border1">
        <BeginStoryboard>
            <Storyboard>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="MyGrid" 
                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" From="0" To="40" 
                    Duration="0:0:1" BeginTime="0:0:0"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </BeginStoryboard>
    </EventTrigger>
</StackPanel.Triggers>
        <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="Black" Height="40" Name="Border1"></Border>
        <Grid Height="0" x:Name="MyGrid" Background="Green" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: this will not work because if you use SourceName, the border has to be a child of the grid.

Comment: Yeah. I'm sorry. I fixed it, but I am late anyway ;) Thank you